# How to study to learn differential geometry for applying it to statistics

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, information-geometry

Basically I want to learn information geometry or specifically the application of differential geometry in statistics to do a project. I am from a statistical background and have a knowledge about real analysis, several variable calculus, linear algebra.
One of my professors told me that the first three chapters from Do Carmo's Differential geometry would be sufficient.
Can someone assure me if that's enough or do I need to learn Riemannian geometry.
And If I need to learn Riemannian geometry then what should be my path for learning.
I don't want to learn rigorous mathematics. I just want to apply it to statistics.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86734/does-differential-geometry-have-anything-to-do-with-statistics

Comment: I have read that post..But the recommended books there require some mathematical maturity.Like I can't understand Amari's books without any knowledge of differential geometry.

Comment: I have only glanced at the book of Murray and Rice, and that was almost 20 years ago, but my recollection is that it was relatively accessible and developed the necessary differential-geometric language as it went along

Comment: Our department head, a statistician, apparently says this book is good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_on_Manifolds_(book) He is a very theoretically-minded person FWIW. This book might also be helpful: https://www.routledge.com/Differential-Geometry-and-Statistics/Murray-Rice/p/book/9780412398605

Comment: @DavidRoberts Indeed, the 2nd book you link to is the one mentioned in the link that Mirco gives, and which I mentioned in my previous comment :)

Comment: @Yemon gah, I totally missed that, both times! :-/

Answer (score 5):

Avishek, not easy to answer with the little context you provided.

I would go first with what your prof said, and yes, Do Carmo is the place to go.

There, you will learn all about surfaces in $R^n$, which is basically classical differential geometry.

If, on the other hand, your project is at the research level (say master thesis or beyond), then download this [article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.08271.pdf). That has to do with abstract information geometry, which in turn relies on modern differential geometry: manifolds, tensor calculus, etc. Basically, the chief difference between the first and the second is that in manifold theory you do not start from embedded manifold, rather you define the entire machinery intrinsically.

If you do not know classic geometry of surfaces, you still have to spend a few days on Do Carmo. Then prepare for a lot of sweat, to get into the modern approach.

Hope it helps

Comment: I am going to do a project for my master's thesis.Now I have studied Do Carmo till regular surfaces.How much should I read.

Comment: And after finishing it ,what book should I follow to study  rest of the  modern approach.

Comment: I have no one to ask .As very few people whom I know are working on this .So please guide me through this

Comment: How about all of it? At least a cursory look. If you go directly into manifold theory it will sound a bit exotic, but if you are steeped in the classical one, it will make sense (after a while).

Comment: Then download this one: https://im0.p.lodz.pl/~kubarski/AnalizaIV/Wyklady/L-Tu-1441973990.pdf. Just found it, but looks as easy going as it comes.

Comment: Should I read this book on manifold totally or should I read a part of it?

Comment: My friend, how can I possibly know? I can tell you that in that book there is more than some basic math grad course in manifolds, so I would download it, show it to your prof, and ask. I would assume that you need only the fundamentals of differentiable manifolds, but ask him anyway

Answer (score 2):

I think Do Carmo is a good option. Personally,  I'm a fan of John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and its sequel Riemannian Manifolds. While these are written at a higher level, they really emphasize the geometric picture at work.

I think the survey by Nielsen is a good article and I found it very helpful to get a broad overview of IG. However, I would not recommend using it to learn differential geometry. Most books about information geometry take a very idiosyncratic approach to geometry, which can give rise to various misunderstandings. These are not a big deal if you are already familiar with differential geometry but are more of a problem if you are trying to learn it.

Both of these works are well worth reading if you are interested in IG, but I'll give an example of what I mean. Both Amari's book and the survey article by Nielsen state that the holonomy of a flat connection is trivial (although they don't use this language). In information geometry, the flat connections of interest are generally on exponential families (where this ends up being true). However, in general, the holonomy of a flat connection is not zero (it's induced by fundamental group). Furthermore, for this result, the connection must be both curvature- and torsion-free (not just curvature-free). Statistical manifolds are generally taken to have torsion-free connections, so this is not an issue in applications. These are relatively minor points if you are familiar with differential geometry, but would be misleading for someone learning it.

Comment: If I want to read Amari's Information geometry and it's application totally,How much Differential geometry should I know.and from which book should I learn that as a beginner,

Comment: That's a good question, and I don't really have a good answer. The issue is that Amari's books aren't trying to be fully rigorous and so have a lot of things that aren't exactly right. I suspect in applications that these issues don't matter and that I'm splitting hairs, but on the other hand I think differential geometry is a topic where it's easy to go astray.

Comment: But if you want to learn differential geometry, I would highly recommend Lee's books (Spivak's textbooks are also really good) and to keep those as reference texts. As I mentioned in my answer, information geometry takes a somewhat idiosyncratic approach to differential geometry, which is rooted in affine differential geometry and considers embeddings quite a bit more than is traditionally done. [cont.]

Comment: Stylistically, I think the DG textbooks that are most similar to Amari's approach are Foundations of Differential Geometry by Nomizu and Kobayashi, and Affine Differential Geometry: Geometry of Affine Immersions by Nomizu and Sasaki. However, these are written at a much more advanced level. They also emphasize a "structural point of view," which avoids any sort of pictures. To be honest, something like Do Carmo which focuses on surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is probably a better way to learn about embeddings for the first time. [cont.]

Comment: Personally, the resource that was most helpful to me for learning information geometry was reading a series of blog posts by John Baez and working through some calculations involving the multinomial and Gaussian families. I would highly recommend working through a few examples in detail, because otherwise it might seem like there is a huge amount of machinery but not much to say about them. Once I considered a few common exponential families, everything became a lot more clear.